# Qgis server - tiles are not rendered when version is set to 1.3.0

Tags: openlayers, qgis-server

I am playing with qgis server and just plain openlayers 3 as a client. With the following code i get the map ro render properly:

```
var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
      code: 'EPSG:32633',
      units: 'm',
      axisOrientation: 'neu'
  });

var map = new ol.Map({
        target : "map-panel",
        layers : [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
              url: 'http://192.168.200.142:8081/cgi-bin/project/qgis_mapserv.fcgi',
              params: {'FORMAT': "image/png", 
                       'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                       tiled: true,
                       LAYERS: 'roads',
                       STYLES: '',
              }
            })
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          projection: projection
        })
    });
```

If i change the VERSION parameter of the WMS request to 1.3.0, qgis server returns blank tiles (requests are processed). Why is that? I am running 2.14.0 64bit on Linux Mint

EDIT: Here is the actual request URL (when version is set to 1.3.0):

http://192.168.200.142:8081/cgi-bin/project/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&tiled=true&LAYERS=roads&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A32633&STYLES=&BBOX=5472872.718699152%2C625471.1678513326%2C5629240.510661985%2C781838.9598141655' -H 'Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: session_id=ac18ac6c07b8da6034fae3c3ae6a5a3ed7e61f87' -H 'Host: 192.168.200.142:8081' -H 'Referer: http://192.168.200.142/apps/app' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'

Comment: can you capture the actual request sent to the server?

Comment: i have added the actual request...

Comment: there is nothing in the qgis server error log, and getcapabilities works for both versions...